# How to disappear field value based on condition in odoo

Tags: odoo

I want to set the value of a field  to null based on Boolean field value.

While creating customer if i check the field is company. a create button will appear .after clicking on create button a new view page is opening. in that view page use company address field is there .I want when i  uncheck that box the address field  should be blank. That should not take the company address that i field in parent view.
i inherited the res.partner module and override  the function onchange_address(). here is my code.

```
def onchange_address(self, cr, uid, ids, use_parent_address, parent_id, context=None):
    def value_or_id(val):
        """ return val or val.id if val is a browse record """
        return val if isinstance(val, (bool, int, long, float, basestring)) else val.id
    result = {}
    if parent_id:
        if ids:
            partner = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
            if partner.parent_id and partner.parent_id.id != parent_id:
                result['warning'] = {'title': _('Warning'),
                                        'message': _('Changing the company of a contact should only be done if it '
                                                'was never correctly set. If an existing contact starts working for a new '
                                                'company then a new contact should be created under that new '
                                                'company. You can use the "Discard" button to abandon this change.')}
        if use_parent_address :
            parent = self.browse(cr, uid, parent_id, context=context)
            address_fields = self._address_fields(cr, uid, context=context)
            result['value'] = dict((key, value_or_id(parent[key])) for key in address_fields)

        elif use_parent_address == False:
            result['value'] = {'street': '','street2': '','city': '','state_id':False,'country_id':False,'zip': ''}


    else:
        result['value'] = {'use_parent_address': False}
    return result
```